# Recycle views in scrollview in android

Tags: android

I have a `scrollview` in which I have inflated the view dynamically (same as facebook wall of android app, there is an `imageview` and `textview` in it.).
All the images are dynamic. If I load too much data in it then I get `outofmemory exception`. I know that `listview` will solve my problem but I cannot use the `listview`.
So, is there any way to optimize i.e recycle the views when they are not visible?

Comment: why can't you use listview?

Comment: my page is same as profile page of facebook android app.That is why i cannot use listview.

Answer (score 2):

By your comments, I believe you still can use a list view:

A listview can have many different kinds of view. For more information on this, read [Android ListView with different layouts for each row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4777272/android-listview-with-different-layout-for-each-row).

This way, views will be recycled and hopefully your memory usage will be smaller.

Anyway, **I would probably investigate your code** as I guess that for running out of memory, you probably are leaking objects or doing something way too many times than needed.

Answer (score 1):

```
you can not handle Errors in normal circumstance but you can use following techneques to remove thias errror
1-Please clear your Arraylist before item add .
2-Use garbage collection techniques 
System.gc() or finalize method use for Memory reclaim from object.
```